# readr::read_csv issue: numbers become double/character

Tags: r, excel, csv

I'm trying to import a large dataset (more 150 columns, csv-file) to RStudio, however I am stuck with manually choosing "numeric" for all the columns, as they seem they import in "double" or "character" default mode. This takes a lot of time for large files. 
Here is the code:

```
> Test_example <- read_csv("~/Desktop/Test_example.csv", 
+     col_types = cols(c_perc = col_number(), 
+         n_perc = col_number(), treatment = col_integer()), 
+     na = "0")
```

I've tried using "stringsAsFactors" command but it does not work.
Also if I do not sign the columns a format when importing, I get error:

```
"Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  .default = col_integer()
)
See spec(...) for full column specifications."
```

Comment: Double shouldn't be a problem as that includes numeric and integer data.  The columns being converted probably have hidden characters in those columns so R coerces it to class "character."

Comment: I think maybe you have some non-numeric characters in these columns. Did you check the file to see if it is the case? If it is, it would be useful to use `sed` (if you're on Linux) to remove those characters at once. After that, it should be fine to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

Check the help on the function. 
If you specify `col_types` you need a specification for all 150 columns or use `cols_only()`
You could also use a compact string like "cid" for character, integer, double
You could try letting the function guess as well.